# writing counter with python

Tags: python, html

I am writing a counter for my webpage using python. And my code is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
print """#Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n 
<html>
<center>
<p>The webpage has been accessed for</p>"""
f=open( "number.txt", "r" )
count = f.read()
n = int( count )
f.close()
f=open( "number.txt", "w" )
f.write( str(n+1) ) 
f.close()
print "<p>"+count+"</p>"
print """<p>times</p>
</center>
</html>
"""
```

When I opened the webpage, only half of the page can be shown. Then I opened the source code of the page, only the following code was shown:

```
<html>
<center>
<p>The webpage has been accessed for</p>
```

After that, I tried another version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
print """#Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n 
<html>
<center>
<p>The webpage has been accessed for</p>"""
f=open( "number.txt", "r" )
count = f.read()
n = int( count )
print "<p>"+count+"</p>"
print """<p>times</p>
</center>
</html>
""" 
f.close()
f=open( "number.txt", "w" )
f.write( str(n+1) ) 
f.close()
```

It works better but not what I expected:

```
<html>
<center>
<p>The webpage has been accessed for</p>
<p>40</p>
<p>times</p>
</center>
</html>
```

The code is ok but I found that the counter can't update itself!
What can I do about it?

Comment: What do you mean the counter can't update itself? The `number.txt` file has the update version of the count each time so if you run your script again you'll get the updated count. For example, running your script and opening `number.txt`, it has the value `41` stored which seems updated to me.
What exactly is your end goal?

Comment: Are you sure the hash before the content header is supposed to be there?

Comment: Are you sure your Python script has permissions to edit the file? Try setting the `number.txt`'s permissions to 777.

Comment: Your code looks like PHP from 10 years ago... Please look into web frameworks like flask or bottle! They're really tiny and solve so many common problems (setting headers, parsing the request etc.) and save you lots of frustration.

Comment: I get it now. My file didn't have permission to edit the txt file. I set the permission to 755. What's the difference between 755 & 777?

Answer (score 1):

Your coding is working fine as is. As others pointed out in the comments, you might want to check your file permissions.

I rewrote your code a little bit, its generally [better to use the `with` functionality](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) in Python for handling file objects. I also used [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to make your print statements a little neater / easier to read:

```
with open( "count.txt", "r" ) as f:
    count = f.read()

output = """#Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n 
<html>
<center>
<p>The webpage has been accessed for</p>
<p>{count}</p>
<p>times</p>
</center>
</html>
""".format(count=count)

count = int(count)
with open( "count.txt", "w" ) as f:
    f.write( str(count+1) )

print(output)
```